# Java error about (error: cannot find symbol)

Tags: java

[image: java]

It giving me this error:

```
    circle.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    C1.getData();
      ^
    symbol:   method getData()
    location: variable C1 of type circle
    circle.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    C1.getResult();
      ^
   symbol:   method getResult()
   location: variable C1 of type circle
   2 errors
```

Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  int r;
  double area, circum;

  void getData() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter Raius of Circle:");
    r = scan.nextInt();
  }

  void getResult() {
    area = 3.14 * r * r;
    circum = 2 * 3.14 * r;
    System.out.println("\n Area of Circle =" + area);
    System.out.println("\nCircumference of Circle=" + circum);
  }
}

public class circle {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    circle C1 = new circle();
    C1.getData();
    C1.getResult();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Try switching the lines `public class Main{` and `public class circle{`

Comment: As @GreenCloakGuy says: You've switched your two classes around. The `Main` class contains the methods you're trying to invoke, while your `Circle` class only contains your `main` method.

Comment: It Still Not working

Comment: Correct indentation will help everybody to read your code - yourself included.

Comment: any suggestion what should i do

Comment: `Main C1 = new Main();`

Comment: `getData` and `getResult` are methods of `Main` class. Replace `circle C1 = new circle();` by `Main C1 = new Main();`

Comment: There's a problem with your class naming... replace Main with Circle and vice versa...

Comment: Your classes do not have any related to each other.
the circle class does not contain any method `getData()` or `getResult()` as you invoke in the main method, it only exist in the Main class.

    public static void main(String[] args) 

This method stand for java entry point, it does not mean it will contains `getData()` or `getResult()`

Comment: Thanks You Everyone It worked again Thankssss